# Can I run user pods on Openshift master or Infra nodes

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

New to openshift so I am bit confused if we can run user pods on master or infra nodes. We have 2 worker nodes and one master and infra nodes each making 4 nodes. The reason for change is to share the loads between all 4 nodes rather than 2 compute nodes.

By reading some documents it seems possible to assign 2 roles to one node but is there any security risk or is it not best practice?

Running on openshift version v3.11.0+d699176-406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if we can run user pods on master or infra nodes

Yes, you absolutely can, the easiest way is to configure that at installation time, refer to https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/example_inventories.html#multi-masters-using-native-ha-ai for example

> is there any security risk or is it not best practice

Running single master node or a single infra node is already a risk to high availability of your cluster. If master fails - your cluster is basically headless, if infra node fails - you lose your internal registry and routers - thus losing an external access or an ability to create new images for your imagestreams. This also applies to host OS upgrades, you will have to reboot master and infra nodes some day, are you okay with having a guaranteed downtime during patching? What if something goes wrong during update?

Regarding running user workload on master and infra nodes - if you are not running privileged SCCs (which can allow to run privileged pods or using any uids on system etc) - you are somewhat safe from container breach, assuming there are no known bugs in container engine you are using. However you should pay close attention to your resource consumption and avoid running any workloads without CPU and memory limits, because overloading master node may result in cluster degradation. You should also monitor disk usage, since running user pods results in more images loaded to your docker storage.

So basically it boils down to this:

Better have multiple master (ideally 3) and couple of infra nodes than a single point of failure for both of these roles. Having separate master and worker nodes is of course better than hosting them together, but multimaster setup even with user workloads should be more resilient if you are watching resource usage carefully.